# Applying dwc2.dtbo to bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb at build time triggering FDT_ERR_NOTFOUND

Tags: device-tree

I'm trying to build a NixOS image for my Raspberry Pi 4b with the dwc2 device tree overlay applied.

Per advice from the #nixos-aarch64 IRC channel, doing this the Nix Way calls for configuring `hardware.deviceTree`, and letting the build process apply the overlay. I'm attempting to do so as follows:

```
hardware.deviceTree.base = "${pkgs.raspberrypifw}/share/raspberrypi/boot/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb";
hardware.deviceTree.overlays = [
  "${pkgs.raspberrypifw}/share/raspberrypi/boot/overlays/dwc2.dtbo"
];
```

...which results in the build process doing the following:

```bsh
for dtb in $(find /nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb -name "*.dtb" ); do
  outDtb=$out/$(realpath --relative-to "/nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb" "$dtb")
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$outDtb")"
  fdtoverlay -o "$outDtb" -i "$dtb" "/nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/overlays/dwc2.dtbo";
done
```

Extracting the command from the script and running it on its own (with `-v` added for verbosity), I can manually reproduce the same error shown in the Nix build logs:

```
+ /nix/store/p3g23lbda8cnzxq84ya63wn34ca5imz9-dtc-1.5.1/bin/fdtoverlay -v -o /home/chaduffy/tmp/dtb-test/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb -i /nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb /nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/overlays/dwc2.dtbo
input  = /nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
output = /home/chaduffy/tmp/dtb-test/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
overlay[0] = /nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/overlays/dwc2.dtbo

Failed to apply '/nix/store/dn9n503g8ckl8r9xnz68wwb5zvfx48s1-raspberrypi-firmware-1.20190925/share/raspberrypi/boot/overlays/dwc2.dtbo': FDT_ERR_NOTFOUND
```

Behavior is identical if instead of trying to use `${pkgs.raspberrypifw}/share/raspberrypi/boot/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb` as the base DTB against which the overlay is applied I use `${pkgs.linux_rpi4}/dtbs/broadcom/bcm2838-rpi-4-b.dtb`.

---

**How can I create a device tree for the Raspberry Pi 4b that has `dwc2.dtbo` folded in ahead-of-time? Why does this `FDT_ERR_NOTFOUND` occur?**

Comment: What is wrong with `/boot/overlays/dwc2.dtbo` or the existing dtoverlay?

Comment: @Milliways, works perfectly if I create `/boot/overlays` by hand and add a `dtoverlay=dwc2` line to `config.txt`, but the NixOS image builder doesn't create the `overlays` directory at all, and according to feedback I've gotten on IRC from the nixos-aarch64 peeps, setting `hardware.deviceTree.overlays` (which runs `fdtoverlay` as described above) is the only mechanism they intend to support.

Comment: This is weird, because other overlays seem to work, e.g.: `overlays = [ "${pkgs.device-tree_rpi.overlays}/vc4-fkms-v3d.dtbo" ];`